# Has anyone created a Hudson or Jenkins Job to deploy to an AWS Beanstalk Instance?

Tags: tomcat, hudson, jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to move an app I have to beanstalk. I want to have an easy automated way to promote new builds though. The console interface in beanstalk is nice: I can just get the war file and upload it. However, it would be nice if I could just run a Jenkins job and have it deploy when it finished building the war file.

I found a thread on here about doing ssh to a beanstalk instance. But there is probably more to it because Beanstalk is probably a cluster with a master that wants to be the deploy manager.

Worth doing or should I just accept the upload page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Maven for your builds, I wrote a plugin to automate beanstalk and Elastic MapReduce deployment:

http://beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br/

I'm looking for testers! :)

Comment: Awesome, will check this out tomorrow!

Comment: Rob, I'm just finishing the missing touches once I get some extra details. Meanwhile, you can watch the AWS fora, where there is a pom.xml suitable for Continuous Delivery into Beanstalk

Answer (score 1):

Afaik beanstalk has a web interface so you could create a selenium script to upload it for you. That would be a bit of a hack though.

Uploading via ssh or so it probably a good option. Also beanstalk has an API (http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/01/aws-beanstalk-apis-and-command-line-tools.html) that you could easily use from a script and then executed from hudson.

If you use a maven build you could have the build do the deployment invocation as part of e.g. the maven deploy phase after a successful build including unit tests..

Comment: Hack using selenium sounds like crazy idea, but ssh put is more reasonable, yet you have to know where it is. API is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

I also didn't manage to find a Jenkins plugin to do so.

A good first step would be Luca's Beanstalk upload script to build a Jenkins plugin:
https://github.com/blanq/beanstalk-upload

Answer (score 0):

You can try [jcabi-beanstalk-maven-plugin](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-beanstalk-maven-plugin/index.html), which automates deploying by [CNAME swap](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html). It's an experimental plugin with specific focus on this particular deployment strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI: I released a Plugin for that:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AWSEB+Deployment+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

you can use Khan Academy's open source jenkins ec-2 plugin.
https://github.com/Khan?page=2